# .htaccess variables REWRITING but not REDIRECTING

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, asp-classic, url-rewriting, query-string

I've been looking for my answer for 2 days but since I haven't found it, I finally decided to put my question to you.

I'm using a Brinkster shared host and can access the .htaccess but no Apache configuration. Every folder on the server represents the content of one site (domain). In the root I have a .htaccess where every domain is controled with

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^(?:www\.)?domainname\.be$
RewriteRule (.*) /folder/$1 [NC,L,NS]
```

In the folder I have another .htacces file. 
I want to rewrite and redirect for prettier URLs
    http://www.domainname.com/pag.asp?name=var_name&id=var_id
should look like
     http://www.domainname.com/name/

The rewrite bit works with the .htaccess code bellow.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
RewriteBase /folder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^name=([a-zA-Z-]+)&id=([0-9]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?page\.asp$ /%1? [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

But for some reason www.domainname.com/name/ always gives a 404.
What am I doing wrong?
Any help wouldd be highly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Surely if you're using classic asp then you're on IIS rather than Apache?  If it's IIS7 or 8 then you can put your rewrite rules in web.config

Comment: Also, on IIS7 and later, Classic ASP is disabled by default and needs to be enabled, otherwise it will treat pages with the .asp extension as if they don't exist and give you a 404 error.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply John. On Brinkster I can run .ASP and .PHP next to each other

Comment: That still suggests you're on IIS.  PHP can be installed on IIS, and most Windows shared hosting packages offer it these days.  The only way I've heard of to get ASP to run on Apache is with a Perl module which only allows you to use Perl as your server side scripting language, and most ASP developers use VBScript.  I believe there is a way using an ISAPI filter to get IIS to read an .htaccess file, but web.config is the standard configuration file to use

Comment: Thank you John, I've looked into it and will start configuring the web.config. Thanks for the braintime